# How to lazy-load child collections in a single step

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am working on a legacy application where NHibernate has been used without any apparent thought to efficiency.  I am currently stepping through a method in which over 200 queries have been executed so far.  This is mostly due to the N+1 problem.

Anyway, as I think about fixing this, my question is:

Given an entity with, say, 10 child collections, almost all of which will be accessed during a single operation, is there a way to lazy-load each child collection in a single call rather than have NHibernate lazy-load each individual child record as it is accessed (e.g., in a foreach loop, which is what's happening now).  It seems to me that eager loading all of these child collections at once would be a massive query and not very performant.  But obviously this N+1 approach is wrong.  How can I tell NHibernate to do a query that loads up the whole child collection on demand?  This still gives me 11 queries, but it's better than 200 and, perhaps, better than the massive query I'd have to do if I eager loaded everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method NHibernateUtil.Initialize(yourObject.ChildCollection). This method forces proxies to load their data based on their fetching strategy, that you set in your mappings. Source: [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-initialization)